# Type Error Object not a function when adding SMS plugin Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sms, cordova-plugins

Trying to use the

> cordova-sms-plugin

to add sms functionality in to the app.
I have done the installation as mentioned in the docs ->
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/

I add the line

```
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';
```

But when I add

```
public sms: SMS
```

in to the constructor arguments it throws in the below error in the JS console and the page stops working.

> core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at index.js:93
>       at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/sms/index.js (index.js:142)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/app/pages/sendtext/sendtext.page.ts (pages-sendtext-sendtext-module.js:92)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/app/pages/sendtext/sendtext.module.ts (pages-sendtext-sendtext-module.js:18)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:32
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:14060)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)

This is just a basic ionic installation with the only plugin added being the SMS plugin.
Any help is appreciated.

Below is my dependencies section in the package.json file.

> "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
>       "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
>       "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
>       "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
>       "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
>       "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.21",
>       "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.18.0",
>       "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.21",
>       "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.21",
>       "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.16",
>       "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
>       "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
>       "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
>       "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.5",
>       "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
>       "cordova-sms-plugin": "0.1.13",
>       "core-js": "^2.5.4",
>       "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
>       "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
>     },

Comment: i hope you added this module in app.Module.

Comment: Added the line import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms'; in app.module. Did not add it to any providers or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Add module somethig like...

```
import { SMS} from '@ionic-native/sms';
@NgModule({
  providers: [
   SMS
  ]
})
```

Comment: Still get an error saying index.js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: try with rebuild development environment with `ionic serve -l`

Comment: I have removed the plugin references from every page. Only have the import in the app.module page and have SMS in the providers list. I still get the same error. But the app's first page doesn't load at all.

Comment: please make sure you following these steps, 
1. add sms pligin with `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sms-plugin` and `npm install --save @ionic-native/sms`
2. Add `sms` in `app.module` which i mention in above answer
3. then related page you need to add in constructor like `private sms: SMS`
4. now with `this.sms` you can use all methods of sms plugin

Comment: Did a fresh install. the npm install command gave this warning. npm WARN @ionic-native/sms@4.18.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. However, "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.21", is in the package.json file.

Comment: same error message before as well even after the fresh install

Comment: don't use beta version, please add related version

Comment: there are other that fail when I change the versions. These were installed by default when I tried ionic start projectName blank --type=angular. Any idea to solve the version issues

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I was facing this same issue 
In my package.json I just changed sms plugin version and write it same as ionic-native/core which then execute command npm install and when i again serve my project it solved my issue

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/sms": "^5.0.0",
```

Also in your module

```
import { SMS} from '@ionic-native/sms/ngx';
@NgModule({
  providers: [
   SMS
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this

```
npm i rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 promise-polyfill --save
```